# SNMP v3 seems not working

Tags: snmp, snmptrapd

I have an application in PHP(running on ubuntu) which executes some commands depending on some received traps. I have a windows test client to send traps and it works well for snmp v2. I check everything from the snmptrapd log. Unfortunately the client doesn't support v3 and I must use a real device. When I use a  NoBreak which sends only v3 traps snmptrapd does nothing. In fact I can see these traps on my windows client, therefore some setup in linux appears to be missing. I've been reading net-snmp page and tutorials on the internet, but I'm not really sure about what to do, because I didn't configure any aspect of security in windows and it simply works. 
If you go to net-snmp docs, it's said that we need to create a user and set a password, however the nobreak seems to send a kind of broadcast. Also I didn't receive instructions for setup(I'm not saying that I don't need to do so). 
The first question is:
How can I listen to a port in order to check trap reception? Maybe it's arriving but not being processed.

The second question:
How can I configure snmptrapd to receive all v3 traps? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Net-SNMP's `snmptrapd` very much does handly SNMPv3 traps.  **But**, it does so only after you've configured it.  In fact, the it won't receive any traps over any version of the protocol unless you configure it.  This is for security, since it is capable of running applications when a trap is received, etc.  Imagine getting a fake trap that told you the machine across town was having an issue?  You'd drive all the way over there just to find out someone had sent you a bugs trap because you were accepting and believing any message that came it's way.

To set up SNMPv3 for `snmptrapd`, you might start with this tutorial in particular: [SNMPv3 Traps](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:snmptrap_SNMPv3)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Wes. In fact I've already read this tutorial. What is unclear to me is how I configure my nobreak(or any other device) to send snmp traps in a proper way, or, on the other hand, how I adapt my traphandler to understand the configuration of my nobreak. I'm in doubt because it seems both sides must be "paired" but I'm not sure if I can do something on the nobreak side.

Comment: The nobreak side should let you set those same standard parameters that the above tutorial talks about: username, authentictation type, authentication master passphrase (or a key, privacy type, and privacy passphrase (or key).  I'm not familiar with nobreak, so I don't know what your options are.